# Executing PHP with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to run a php file with AJAX from my "main.php".

The problem is that it doesnt let my stay on the main.php and moves me to "tallennus.php", when I want to stay at "main.php". The tallennus.php should be done on the background.

"tallennus.php" does it's work perfectly (saves data to database). But I want to stay on mainsite while it does it.

Im trying to use AJAX to run "tallennus.php" on the background.

Why does the site change from main.php to tallennus.php?

```
<button onclick="testi()">testi</button><br>
<script>
function testi()
{
    alert("function started");
    var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
            }
            xmlhttp.open("get", "tallennus.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }   




</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default type of `<button>` is `type="submit"`, so it submits the form. Change it to `type="button"`.

```
<button type="button" onclick="testi()">testi</button><br>
```

---

As per the following reference:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.html

*"A button element with no type attribute specified represents the same thing as a [button element with its type attribute set to "submit"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html#button.submit)."*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by doing this:

```
<script>
function tallenna()
{


    var tunnus=document.getElementById('tunnus').value;
    var nimi=document.getElementById('nimi').value;
    var deadline=document.getElementById('deadline').value;
    var vaihe=document.getElementById('vaihe').value;
    var dataString=
    'tunnus='+ tunnus + 
    '&nimi='+ nimi+
    '&deadline='+ deadline+
    '&vaihe='+ vaihe;

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "tallennus.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache:false,
        success:function(html){
            $('#msg').html(html);
        }
    });

    document.getElementById("frm").reset();// for clearing form
    return false;

}
</script>

<br><input type="submit" value="TALLENNA" onclick="return tallenna()">
```